# Trying to use RPi Zero W as USB keyboard

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb

I'm using a RPi Zero W for this exercise. I downloaded 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-full.zip and installed it onto a 32G microSD card:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-full.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

Booted my RPi Zero W using the aforementioned microSD card and immediately update the system:

```
apt-get update
```

Added the following two lines at the end of /etc/modules:

```
dwc2
libcomposite
```

Then executed the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create gadget
mkdir /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/mykeyboard
cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/mykeyboard

# Add basic information
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # Version 1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB # USB 2.0
echo 0x00 > bDeviceClass
echo 0x00 > bDeviceProtocol
echo 0x00 > bDeviceSubClass
echo 0x08 > bMaxPacketSize0
echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x1d6b > idVendor # Linux Foundation

# Create English locale
mkdir strings/0x409

echo "My manufacturer" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "My virtual keyboard" > strings/0x409/product
echo "0123456789" > strings/0x409/serialnumber

# Create HID function
mkdir functions/hid.usb0

echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/protocol
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb0/report_length # 8-byte reports
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/subclass

# Write report descriptor
echo "05010906a101050719e029e71500250175019508810275089501810175019503050819012903910275019505910175089506150026ff00050719002aff008100c0" | xxd -r -ps > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc

# Create configuration
mkdir configs/c.1
mkdir configs/c.1/strings/0x409

echo 0x80 > configs/c.1/bmAttributes
echo 200 > configs/c.1/MaxPower # 200 mA
echo "Example configuration" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration

# Link HID function to configuration
ln -s functions/hid.usb0 configs/c.1

# Enable gadget
ls /sys/class/udc > UDC
```

I then plugged the RPi Zero into my Fedora 29 laptop expecting to see the RPi show up when I executed: ***lsusb -t*** with the device (my RPi Zero) showing up with ***Class=Human Interface Device***.

Nothing shows up, except my known devices.

I know this is an exercise in ConfigFS and how to use it to turn your micro-micro-micro Linus board into a "USB gadget".

Any suggestions?

Comment: I found this similar case here https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/ The code looks very similar except it have some extra codes here and there. Maybe you might be missing something somewhere. It also have a python script. I think is simulates keyboard keys.

Comment: That Python code is for testing purposes. The RPi should immediately identify itself as an USB "human interface device" and you should see that with "lsusb -t".